# Is there something called function of two dependent variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

While reading in Stewart calculus in the section that talks about implicit differentiation in multivarible functions he wrote this :

if $F(x,y)=0$ that define implicitly a differentiable function in $x$ ,$y=f(x)$

where $F(x,f(x))=0$ and then he applied the chain rule

\begin{gather} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{d y}{dx}=0 \end{gather}

so he treated $F$ as being function of $2$ variables although one of them is depending on the other

I think this like the composite function in single variable calc, sometimes we write functions in terms of composition between others

\begin{gather} h(x)=f(x^2)=sin(x^2) \end{gather}

the function $h$ it's input is $x$ while the function $f$ it's input it $x^2$ and that is obvious while taking the chain rule we write

\begin{gather} \frac{d h(x)}{dx}=\frac{d f(x^2)}{d(x^2)}\frac{d(x^2) }{dx} \end{gather}

which is an indication that the term $(x^2)$ is the variable to $f$ even that it's connected to $x$

then if it applicable to single variable calc , then it can also be applicable to multivariable ?

correct me if I wrote anything wrong .

Comment: " function of two dependent variables"? Not very clear... We have [functions with one argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) $f(x)$ and [functions with many arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_real_variables) $g(x,y,z)$. All have a single value for every input: the input value is sometimes called the "independent variable".

Comment: Then we have also [Multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function) aka: many-valued function, that are a set-valued function, like e.g. the *square root* that may be considered a multivalued function because every real number greater than zero has two real square roots.

Comment: So, what do you mean with "function of two dependent variables"? A function of two **independent** variables, or a function with two values for every input?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA

if $z=F(x,y)$ and also $y=g(x)$ that makes $z=F(x,g(x)) $ the term $g(x)$ depend on $x$ and input to $z$ which makes $z$ has inputs of $x$ and $g(x)$

Comment: Ok; in that case yes, you apply the "chain rule" to the second argument, because you want to compute the partial derivative in terms of the argument $x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA

could we say in that case $z=F(x,g(x))$ still a function of $2$ variables ?

Comment: @amin It's up to you how you want to treat the function. If you want, you can see it as a function of two variables and the partial derivatives wrt $x$ and $y$ will give you information on how the function behaves when you vary only one and not the other. "Wait" you may say "but $y$ is a function of $x$, when I vary $x$ I also vary $y$!" -- so no, not if you treat them as independent from one another, and there are often very good reasons to do that. OTOH there are also good reasons sometimes to want the "total" derivative with respect to a single variable, if such a thing exists

Comment: @Amit

could you clarify more ? because I'm not getting what you want to say

Comment: @amin I am saying that what you wrote as $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{d y}{dx} $$ is known as the total derivative of $F$ wrt $x$: $\frac{dF}{dx}$ but that is not the only correct way to differentiate such a function. It's completely legitimate to consider only the partial derivatives in certain cases, all depends on what you want to do

Comment: @Amit so that makes the function $F$ still have $2$ variables although the variable $y$ is $g(x)$ 
like what I wrote $F(x,g(x))$ still be considered has $2$ variables in it

Comment: @amin It means it can be both. Take a real example, $F(x,y)=x+2y$ , $y(x)=x^2$. Clearly by substitution you can also write $F$ as a function  of only $x$. *Neither* is more correct than the other.

Comment: @Amit, but if by substitution $F$ became function of single variable ,how did we have this
\begin{gather}  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{d y}{dx}  
 \end{gather}

what confuse me .is in single variable calc we treat $f(g(x))$ as being function in $g(x)$ and we take derivative w.r.t $g(x)$ 
when applying that to multivarible i get confused
that's why i'm asking if $F(x,g(x))$ is function of 2 varibles beacause i treat $g(x)$ as a whole as a variable .

Comment: @Amit

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}(f\circ g)(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} f( g(x) )}{\mathrm{d}g(x)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}. $$

we write this in chain rule which indicate that $f$ is function of $g(x)$ even if that $g(x)$ is related to $x$,that's the case i'm asking but in multivaraible function

Comment: @amin The chain rule you are mentioning is manifestly present in the second term of $dF/dx$... I think you need to see a derivation of the entire thing for it to make sense

Comment: @Amit

can you recommend any papers or books about the derivation of the entire thing ?

Comment: @amin Spivak's "Calculus on manifolds" is a good one. The confusion often happens about this, because really this is a case of differentiating wrt a vector, not wrt a scalar. The plus sign arises really from a dot product between the gradient and a "small" vector in the (x,y) direction

Comment: @Amit 
I've read the chain rule section on spivak 
and he wrote this $F(x)=f(g_{1}(x),...,g_{m}(x))$
indicating that $f$ is function of several variables of $g_{j} (x) $

Comment: @amin so what is the question?

Comment: @Amit, isn't that confirming what i've said ?

if $f(g_{1}(x),...,g_{m}(x))$ is still function of several variables 

then that makes $f(x,g(x))$ still function of several variables , is that right ?

Comment: @amin Look carefully at what you wrote. $F(x)$ and $f(g_1(x),\dots,g_m(x))$ represent the *same* function in two different ways. $F$ is the representation of the function as a function of one variable, $f$ is that of multiple variables. As I already said, *neither of the representation is "right" or "wrong"* it all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Amit 

I just wanted to make sure that if we have some function like $f(x,g(x))$ is still be a mutlivariable function

Comment: @amin Your question is not well defined because you are not giving an explicit form of $f$. If you have something like $f(x,g) = g^2+x$ with $g=2x$ then yes $f$ is still clearly a function of $2$ variables. But now if you substitute $g$: $f(x,g(x))=4x^2+x$ then it is clearly a function only of $x$ and you might as well write $f(x)=4x^2+x$.

Comment: @Amit

if $f(x^2)=sin(x^2)$ that makes $x^2$ the domain of the function $f$
similarly 
if $f(x,x^2)=x+sin(x^2)$ that makes it take $x$,$x^2$ into it's domain

Comment: @amin if $f(x^2)=sin(x^2)$ then $f(x)=sin(x)$ ! No one ever writes something like $f(x,x^2)$ -- it doesn't make sense and will be highly confusing. If you want to treat the $x^2$ that's after the plus sign as an independent variable, you give it a different symbol.

Comment: @Amit 
if so , how do we define the composite function , my confusion lie at this 

all I know about composite function is the it's a function that take the output of another one into it's input that's why i insist on writing $f(x^2)$ indicating that it takes the output of the square function , Could you clarify it because certainly my confusion lies at this area ?

Comment: @amin you will be less confused if you think about functions as their explicit representations. $f(x^2)$ gives you no different information than writing $f(x)$ or $f(\sqrt{t})$ or $f(z^3)$... I suggest you to actually take a few concrete functions:
$$f(x)=x^2+x+1$$
$$g(x)=\sin{x}+x$$
$$h(x)=log(x)+1$$
and calculate 
$$(f \circ g)(x)$$
$$(g \circ f)(x)$$
$$(f \circ (g \circ h))(x)$$
In other words, from what you're saying I think what you're lacking is hands on *practice*. Things can look weird when you're only studying abstractly, you need to do some examples as well to get the idea.